# Coverting from IDocumentSnapshot<T> to a List<T> using Plugin.Firebase.Firestore

Tags: .net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, maui

I am using Plugin.Firebase.Firestore in a Maui app to connect to Firebase Firestore. https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase/blob/development/docs/firestore.md

The model is

```
    public class Pokemon : IFirestoreObject
    {
        [FirestoreDocumentId]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [FirestoreProperty("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [FirestoreProperty("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [FirestoreProperty("Number")]
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
```

I can get my documents from a collection using:

```
        var query = await CrossFirebaseFirestore
            .Current
            .GetCollection("NewCollection")
            .GetDocumentsAsync<Pokemon>();

        var docs = query.Documents;
```

But where I am hung up on is that docs return an IDocumentSnapshot and what I would like to get is just a List.

[image]

Short of iterating through and adding each doc.data into a list manually inside a foreach(docs), is there a way to just cast directly into a List of type Pokemon?

```
        List<Pokemon> allData = new List<Pokemon>();
        
        foreach (var doc in docs)
        {
            allData.Add(doc.Data);
        }
```

Comment: is there a way to just cast directly into a List -nope, manually iterating is the way to go, unless you recreate the same structure as the response which you won't need usually since it's inefficient to use

Comment: The code you're trying to avoid  is `allData.AddRange(docs)`. Internally it does loop. There's no way to avoid looping unless `Documents` is a `List<>` already, in which case you could cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Documents` property is an `IEnumerable`, so you should be able to use Linq rather than a loop. However, it doesn't look there these is anytihng built into that library to do what you are want natively.

You'll need `using System.Linq;` then you can do the following

```cs
        var query = await CrossFirebaseFirestore
            .Current
            .GetCollection("NewCollection")
            .GetDocumentsAsync<Pokemon>();

        var docs = query.Documents
            .Select(snap => snap.Data)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: LINQ *is* looping, with a different syntax. This is actually slower than using a `List<>` with a predefined capacity and `AddRange` due to reallocations

Comment: The performance lost is pretty negligible in most cases. If the OP is looking for more readable syntax and less typing, this is a pretty good option. If you're in the sort of high performance environment where you're concerned about the performance drag of additional method calls, you're right than linq probably isn't the way to go.

Comment: Better than `list.AddRange(docs)` ? The perf hit is anything but negligible. It's a *major* issue and hides behind almost all OutOfMemoryException SO questions. Lists store data in arrays internally. When they get full, a new array is allocated with double the size and the data is copied over. The old buffer gets garbage collected. That's the reason all perf guidance says to use the `List(capacity)` constructor when possible. The biggest performance improvements in .NET Core came from removing unnecessary allocations.

Comment: List.AddRange won't work in this case since he's looking to extract a property of the elements in the collection into a List. There are gotchas with linq, but this use case isn't one of them. There's nothing here that would result in run away allocations.  That usually stems from boxing/unboxing or poorly nested closures, etc.

Comment: `List.Add` causes the allocations, and `ToList` *has* to add items with reallocation because it has no `capacity` argument and no way of knowing how many items there are. `from boxing/unboxing or poorly nested closures, etc.` not the case here at all. Not what the guidelines talk about either

Comment: If the app isn't long lived or you know there are few items every time it's fine to use `ToList()`. If you see increasing memory usage in `Diagnostic Window` while debugging though, that (along with string operations) is the most likely culprit